# Java ExecutorService threads writing to same field

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, executorservice

First post here so hello everyone.
I am building a small client that needs to send heartbeats over socket and recevive various fixed length binary messages over socket.
I have a connection manager class that starts socket connection and creates 2 threads, one to send heartbeats every x seconds. The other thread listens for input.

When it recevies input it reads header into byte array (always 4 bytes) it gets the msg length x = byte[3] then reads the next x bytes to message byte array. It then uses the ExecutorService to create a new messasge processor object which takes in the message byte array.

The messasge processor implements runnable and prints out the message bytes. 
However if the socket receives lots of data i.e. server sending msgs sequentially then my message processor seems to print out mixed data from differnt threads - I thought my executor would create a new object which would be thread safe and have its own instance of binary[] msgBytes.

connectionManager below which creates send / rcv threads, rcv thread creates a thread pool and when reads a message creates new messageProcessor object to process byte[] message

```
public class connectionManager extends Thread {
    public connectionManager(InetAddress host, int serverSocket) {
        System.out.println("in connectionManager create");
        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket(host, serverSocket);
            outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            connected = true;
            final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

            final Thread inThread = new Thread() {
                @Override 
                public void run() {
                    while (connected) {
                        try {
                            DataInputStream dIn = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

                            byte[] header = new byte[4];
                            dIn.readFully(header); // read the message                            

                            String msgType = new String(new byte[]{ header[3] }, "US-ASCII");

                            short length = getShortFromLittleEndianRange(header, 1); //test function to return length offset is start position of length   
                            byte[] message = new byte[length - 1]; //minus the msg type byte

                            dIn.readFully(message);

                            executor.execute(new MessageProcessor(message, msgType));
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                connected = false;
                            } 
                    }
                    executor.shutdown();
                    System.out.println("Shutdown executor");
        };
            };
            inThread.start();          


            final Thread outThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
                public void run() {
                    Heartbeat hb = new Heartbeat();
                    while(connected) {
                        PrintWriter out = null;
                        try {
                            this.sleep(3000);                           
                            outToServer.write(hb.serialize());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            System.out.println("cant send heartbeat server not alive...");
                        }
                    }
        };
            };
            outThread.start();            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot connect to server");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }    
}
```

MessageProcess implements runnable I would expect the executor to create new MessageProcess objects each with its own instance of msgBytes and msgType

```
public class MessageProcessor implements Runnable {

    private byte[] msgBytes;
    private String msgType;

    MessageProcessor(byte[] newMsgBytes, String newMsgType) {
    msgBytes = newMsgBytes; 
    msgType = newMsgType;
    }    

    @Override
    public void run() {
    output();
    }

    synchronized void output() {
        System.out.println("\nMessageProcessor process inbound message " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        System.out.println("message type : " + " " + msgType);
        for(byte b : msgBytes){
            System.out.printf("%02X",b);
        }           
        System.out.println("\nfinished MessageProcessor " + Thread.currentThread().getId());        
    }
}
```

However when I run and receive a 'flood' of msgs from server my consol output looks as though there is a thread safety issue: sample output below.

```
MessageProcessor process inbound message 16
message type : 8

01D40806004530515266385779624C6D653830
MessageProcessor process inbound message 17
2D36667664374E6D6A4100000000000000003030515266444E31417A766846000000000000000000000000020000000000A90DAE0400000001000000000000000000000000FA10000000000100000000000000004C43484C4742324500000052D7048024E3F70400BCBDE256306F0100000203003030515266444E31417A766800000000message type : 8


finished MessageProcessor 16
01D50806004530515266385779624C6D6638302D366676643176584A5200000000000000003030515266444E31417A766246000000000000000000000000010000000000A90DAE0400000001000000090000000109000000FA10000000000200000000000000004C43484C4742324500000041D7048024E3F70400BCBDE256306F0100000003003030515266444E31417A766200000000
finished MessageProcessor 17
```

I would expect to see

```
MessageProcessor process inbound message 16
message type : 8
<hex>

finished MessageProcessor 16

MessageProcessor process inbound message 17
message type : 8
<hex>

finished MessageProcessor 17
```

Am I not threas safe in what I am doing?

Many thanks
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using different instances of `MessageProcessor` (one per message), the `synchronized` label on `output()` does not have the effect I think you are  expecting. Each instance will be able to access its own `output()` without being blocked by the other instances.

The output you see is the intermingling of the outputs from different instances. To prevent the mixing, you could use a `StringBuilder` to construct your output and submit it to `System.out` in a single call. If you want to synchronize the output across the instances, consider using a queue.

Comment: thanks for the quick response - so I'm thread safe its just an out put issue? i.e. if I were to create a message object from the message bytes would each of my message objects have the correct data.

Comment: The data inside your `MessageProcessor` is safe. Assuming you construct the message object in a safe manner, they will be fine.

Comment: many thanks bradimus I changed to StringBuilder and output looks good.